# Magento 2 - Possible Image Corruption

Tags: magento2, media

I have a pair of clients who are both Magento 1 to Magento 2 conversions. After going to Magento 2 and dropping their media in place, if they're running 2.2.7 or 2.2.8, the images look like they've had some sort of corruption take place.

[image: Example of the issue:]

If you look at the image provided, that's what happened. This happens to JPEG images in addition to PNG. Prior to the upgrade to 2.2.8, the client did not see this happening. Does not affect all images, and only some but only started looking this way after upgrading to 2.2.8. Additionally, using the backup I took prior to the upgrade, which was 2.2.5, I did not see the odd white borders around the product itself. When I upgraded to 2.2.8 as a test, it happened again.

A similar issue has happened to another client who I took directly to 2.2.8 from Magento 1.7.

I have tried recreating the products with their images through the API, which is how they were made before but the issue persists. I'd lean towards source images having an issue but why would they work properly on 2.2.5 then look this way on 2.2.8? I have tried `catalog:images:resize` multiple times, but this had no effect.

Is there any kind of solution to this? Did 2.2.7 make some sort of change to image processing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $fileType = $this->getImageType();
    if (in_array($fileType, [IMAGETYPE_PNG, IMAGETYPE_GIF])) {
        $this->_keepTransparency = true;
        if ($this->_imageHandler) {
            $isAlpha = $this->checkAlpha($this->_fileName);
            if ($isAlpha) {
                $this->_fillBackgroundColor($this->_imageHandler);
            }
        }
    }
```

Traced it to this block of code in `vendor/magento/framework/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php`. After commenting this out and rerunning catalog:images:resize, I had no more image problems.